# Extract Data from XML into C# object using LINQ to XML, Enums

Tags: c#, enums, linq-to-xml

I am trying to extract data from XML file and save it my C# class/object.  My problem is

I have an XMl file like this

```
<personal_auto xmlns = "http://cp.com/rules/client"> 
 <claim id = "s1" type = "Subject Section">
    <report > 
    </report> 
    <policy>
    </policy>
 </claim>
 <claim id = "s2" type = "Vehichle Section">
    <report >
    </report>
    <policy>
    </policy>
  </claim>
  <claim id = "s3" type = "Agent Section">>
    <report 
    </report>
    <policy>
    </policy>
  </claim>
</personal_auto>
```

I have an enum like this

```
    public enum typesectionEnum
    {
        [Description("Subject Section")]
        subjectSection,
        [Description("Vehicle Section")]
        vehicleSection,
        [Description("Possible Related Section")]
        possibleRelatedSection,
        [Description("Agent (Summary) Section")]
        AgentSection
    }
```

I am trying to extract data from the XML file and save to my C# class/object.

```
List<claim> = ( from d in query.Descendants(xmlns + "claim")
                 select new Claim 
                   {
                    id = d.Attribute("id").value,
                    type = ????                    
                    }
                 ).ToList (),
```

What I am wondering is, I want to set the value in my application that will access the value in the xml file.

Comment: It bothers me that AgentSection is pascal-case. If you are going to break convention at least be consistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.DESCRIPTIONATTRIBUTE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)s matches exactly with the type attribute strings in the XML you can use reflection.

**Edit: convert to generic**

```
public TEnum GetEnum<TEnum>(string input) where TEnum : struct
{
    if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
        throw new Exception(typeof(TEnum).GetType() + " is not en enum");
    Type dataType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(typesectionEnum));
    foreach (FieldInfo field in
        typeof(typesectionEnum).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField |
        BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        object value = field.GetValue(null);
        foreach (DescriptionAttribute attrib in field.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>())
        {
            if (attrib.Description == input)
            {
                return (TEnum)value;
            }
        }
    }
    return default(TEnum);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
select new Claim 
{
    id = d.Attribute("id").value,
    type = GetEnum<typesectionEnum>(d.Attribute("type").value),
}
```

Comment: @Albin. Thats wonderful. I would like to have the GetEnum method as a Generic one. Thanks M

Comment: Hi Albin, I would like to return DescriptionAttribute instead of the value.How can i achieve that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Madhu Kiran: Change "return (TEnum)value;" to "return attrib;" and "return default(TEnum);" to "return null;", update the method signature to return DescriptionAttribute.

Comment: Hi Albin,Thank you. I get "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no impicit conversion between 'System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute' and 'typesectionEnum'"  at the below line of code  (Marked with ***)                                                           select new Claim  
{ 
    id = d.Attribute("id").value, 
   *** type = GetEnum<typesectionEnum>(d.Attribute("type").value), 
}

Comment: My C# object looks like : public class Claim { public typesectionEnum type { get; set; } }

Comment: @Madhu Kiran, of course you need to change the type of the type field/attribute in the Claim type too.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<claim> claims = ( 
    from d in query.Descendants(xmlns + "claim") 
    let t = d.Attribute("type").Value
    select new Claim  
    { 
        id = d.Attribute("id").value, 
        type =  t == "Subject Section" ? typesectionEnum.subjectSection :
                (t == "Vehicle Section" ? typesectionEnum.vehicleSection :
                 (t == "Possible Related Section" ? typesectionEnum.possibleRelatedSection :
                                                    typesectionenum.AgentSection))
     }
 ).ToList ();
```

Comment: Thank you John that works. Is there a generic way for doing this. Say my typesectionEnum has 20 fields then?

Comment: @Madhu: use Albin's technique below :-)